# Хочу чтобы authorizePage принимал значения log и pas и передавал в controller, но пишет Undefined name 'log','pas'

Tags: flutter

```dart
class authorisePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String log;
  final String pas;
    
  authorisePage({super.key, required this.log, required this.pas});
    
  @override
  State<authorisePage> createState() => _authorisePage();
}
    
class _authorisePage extends State<authorisePage> {
  TextEditingController login = TextEditingController(text: log);
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController(text: pas);
  bool _hidePass = true;
  bool _correctData = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `State` эти значения можно получить из `widget`, при этом к `widget` надо обращаться не ранее, чем в `initState` (читайте про жизненный цикл виджетов для подробностей):

```dart
class _authorisePage extends State<authorisePage> {
  late final TextEditingController login;
  late final TextEditingController password;
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    login = TextEditingController( text: widget.log );
    password = TextEditingController( text: widget.pas );
    // к context тоже если что уже можно обращаться
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    login.dispose();
    password.dispose();
  }
}
```

Не забывайте делать `dispose` для всех объектов, которые это требуют, чтобы память не утекала.